# Error when embedding regular expression (phone numb validate) on xml schema (xsd)

Tags: regex, xsd

I don't understand why this regular expression for validation international phone number gives an error when embedded on xml-schema:

```
<xs:simpleType name="phoneType">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:pattern value="^\+(?:[0-9] ?){6,14}[0-9]$" />
  </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

What's wrong with it? Does support group matching? Why is not supported by [Xml Schema](http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema) ?

Thank you very much.

Indrit

Comment: What regular expression? /<&>&&<<><>>&&/?

Comment: sorry Axeman, there was a visualisation problem

Comment: It works when I tested it.  How can we reproduce your issue?

Comment: Hi Jeremy, 
the regex is ok, but when i put it in xml-schema it doesn't compile(validate). 

For example in Eclipse the msg is: 
InvalidRegex: Pattern value '^\+(?:[0-9] ?){6,14}[0-9]$' is not a valid regular expression. The reported error was: 'This expression is not supported in the current option setting.'.

Also Stylus Studio displays a similar error: 
unexpected meta character

Thank you!

Comment: I think you'll have to go with trial and error.  Delete parts of your regex until it validates.  See if you can find the smallest change that breaks it.

Answer (score 4):

XML schema supports group matching, but not capturing or lookaround. This means that it doesn't the ?: non-capturing group.

According to http://www.regular-expressions.info/xml.html it also doesn't support the ^ and $ anchors.

Comment: Hi solomon-gibbs, thank you for your answer. I think your are right, schemas doesn't support non capturing groups; because I already tried to delete anchors but the problem was still there.  Thank you again.
Indrit

Answer (score 3):

It's probably the anchors (`^` and `$`).  In XML Schema, all [regexes](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#regexs) are implicitly anchored at both ends. Explicit anchors are not supported.

Comment: Hi Alan, thank you too, probably you are right too but in this case the problem wasn't related to anchors. Thank you very much.
Indrit