# How to bypass "This expression is not supported in the current option setting" error

Tags: java, xml, regex, validation, xsd

I'm trying to validate an XML document against an XSD. I'm not allowed to disclose the contents of the XSD **nor** to modify it, being it an official XSD that will be used for server-side validation of the submitted XML report.

I have tried simple validation code using SAX

```
    SchemaFactory schemaFactory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
    
    ClassPathResource resource = new ClassPathResource("path/to/xsd");
    Schema schema = schemaFactory.newSchema(resource.getFile()); //BOOM

    Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
    validator.validate(new StreamSource(xmlFile));
```

The error reported by SAX is

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: InvalidRegex: Pattern value '...' is not a valid regular expression. The reported error was: 'This expression is not supported in the current option setting.' at column '77'.
```

There are more similar errors traced by [this free tool](http://www.utilities-online.info/xsdvalidation/).

I have read that these errors are related to the usage of

- Invalid character classes - [Validating XML using XSD with regex pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2613928/validating-xml-using-xsd-with-regex-pattern)
- Explicit anchors or backreferences - [Error when embedding regular expression (phone numb validate) on xml schema (xsd)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1105159/error-when-embedding-regular-expression-phone-numb-validate-on-xml-schema-xsd)

In my XSD **there are** explicit anchors [edit] and **non-capturing groups** (`(?!`).

Since the error says "This expression is not supported in the **current option setting**"

### How do I

change validation options in Java in order to bypass this error and validate XSD with explicit anchors and backreferences?

#### Update

Ok let me say that separately from the body of the question. By analysing the specific error and finding column 77 of the string, I found the following (starting from column 74): `(?!((N|n)`. The guilty character is the exclamation mark of a non-capturing group. I have analysed the regex itself out of the XML context and it is valid according to the semantics of the datum. So that non-capturing group must stay there to exclude a certain set of patters (that start with case insensitive `n` in this case)

Comment: If the anchors are at the beginning or at the end, remove them. You don't need it. XML validator always validate the expression against the whole string.

Comment: I'm not allowed to modify the schema. It's an official European Union XSD. Though removing the few anchors can be a feasible workaround (even to see if there are still more quirks), we cannot deploy a solution that doesn't validate against the official schema, because documents generated by our software **will** be validated by the server. I was asking if there is any option to allow non-XML-flavoured regexes

Comment: Would you please include that into the question?

Comment: Of course. I also noted that the regex contains lookaheads or whatever they are called (?!). These ones could be a bigger problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that your schema is invalid because it uses regular expressions that are not permitted by the XSD specification.

There are some (so-called) XSD processors that allow non-standard regular expressions; I believe one such is the Microsoft schema processor.

You have only two options: modify the schema to be conforming, or use a schema processor that implements the proprietary extensions used in the schema.

If the schema is indeed an "official European Union XSD" then:

(a) I'm surprised you are not allowed to disclose it

(b) you have every reason to complain that the EU is doing something that doesn't comply with open standards.

Comment: Upvote for (B). For (A), I can tell you about the slogan of http://www.eurodw.eu/: "Restoring confidence through transparency" and then the XML comment: "This XML schema is confidential and should not be disclosed or transmitted......................"

Comment: Accepted because: I just tried to use Visual Studio 2013 and it successfully validated my output document against that XSD. I also voluntarily introduced a pattern error and VS reported the "guilty" element being invalid. At least I did a good job with Java generator

Comment: I looked at the European Data Warehouse project. It does not look to me like an "official EU" thing at all, it looks like a private sector project that is claiming some kind of unspecified EU endorsement.

Comment: I have been told it's endorsed by the ECB, which, to me, makes the whole thing more "official". Anyway I read a non-disclosure statement in the XSD body, so I'll retain from disclosing the contents.

Answer (score 2):

I've been fighting this exact same issue and seemed to have found a solution. I was able to solve this by creating one schema type that checks for trailing space, and then another type that checks for leading space which also extends the other type. This allows me to verify there is no leading or trailing space and also allows for strings with only one character.

Example

```
<xs:simpleType name="trimmedString">
    <xs:restriction base="noTrailingSpaceString">
        <xs:pattern value="[^\s].*"/><!-- prevents leading space and requires at least one character -->
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
<xs:simpleType name="noTrailingSpaceString">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:pattern value=".*[^\s]"/><!-- prevents trailing space and requires at least one character -->
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```